# How to include nulls in Json - while converting a dataframe to json in Spark

Tags: json, apache-spark-sql

How can I get nulls in json after converting Dataframe to Json string in spark

I have tried using Df.toJson but it ignores Null values

```
Eg:
+-------+--------+
|   Col1|Col2    |
+-------+--------+
|  Row1| RowData1| 
|  Row2| RowData2|
|  Row3| null    |
+-------+--------+

Expected:
{"Col1":"Row1","Col2":"RowData1"}
{"Col1":"Row2","Col2":"RowData2"}
{"Col1":"Row3","Col2":}
or

{"Col1":"Row1","Col2":"RowData1"}
{"Col1":"Row2","Col2":"RowData2"}
{"Col1":"Row3","Col2":null}
```

Comment: Do you need the `null` value or a String with the value `"null"` inside?

Comment: Hi @ashish did you manage to solve this one?

Comment: is there a way to achieve this? thanks